# XNA does not display texture of my own fbx model

Tags: xna, textures, blender

Since I've ran out of models during making game in XNA i tried to make my own. But there is a problem - when I making .fbx model, adding texture via blender, doing uv mapping and then applying this model to my XNA project, everything works fine but the texture not displaying. Only thing that I see is the gray model. What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Textures are not saved along with the model file. You have to separately load the texture:

```cs
var texture = Content.Load<Texture>("TextureName");
```

When the texture is loaded you can [bind it to the effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051.aspx):

```cs
basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
basicEffect.Texture = texture;
```